# Showing a local image file in browser

Tags: html, image, angular, typescript, filereader

I'm trying to build a page that lets the user select a local image. It should then be displayed. I'm new to the web world so I googled a lot and basically copied a few other StackOverflow posts. It *should* work. But it doesn't. I can see the file being loaded, it's image data being written to the element, but the element does not change. It just stays white with it's Alternate text displayed.

**app.component.html:**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Sprite Sheet Converter</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="control-label" for="sourceFileControl">Source:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="file" class="form-control" id="sourceFileControl" name="sourceFileControl" (change)="load($event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <img #sourceImage src="" alt="Source" width="100" height="100"/>
    </div>

  </form>

  <img #destinationImage alt="Destination"/>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('sourceImage') sourceImage: HTMLImageElement;
  @ViewChild('destinationImage') destinationImage: HTMLImageElement;

  load(event: EventTarget): void {
    const eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
    const target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
    const files: FileList = target.files;
    const file = files[0];
    console.log(file);

    const reader  = new FileReader();
    const img = this.sourceImage;

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      img.src = reader.result;
      console.log('done loading');
      console.log(img);
    };

    console.log('now loading');
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

**Result after selecting a file**

(debug output to the right, all methods called, just the picture is still empty and showing it's alternate text.)

[image]

So... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for the record, the selected picture is *not* the word "Source" on a white background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `function` keyword, you loose the access to `this`. You need to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() =>` instead. Also, you don't need `ViewChild` in your specific case. I would change your code to following in order to work:

Use [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to make sure that the image does not load until it has data. Bind the image source to some variable that will contain the source image data. Same goes for destination image. Change the `<img>` tags to following:

```
<img *ngIf="sourceImage" src={{sourceImage}} alt="Source" width="100" height="100"/>

<img *ngIf="destinationImage" src={{destinationImage}} alt="Destination"/>
```

... and your component.ts code will look like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  sourceImage: string;
  destinationImage: string;

  load(event: EventTarget): void {
    const eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
    const target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
    const files: FileList = target.files;
    const file = files[0];
    console.log(file);    
    const reader  = new FileReader();    
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      console.log('done loading');
      this.sourceImage = reader.result;

    };

    console.log('now loading');
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check if you are getting **SRC** attribute for  in DOM. If it is there check proper image source is present. Try to give width and height styles to img element

Comment: My image element *has* width and height. In my DOM, the `src` says `unknown` indeed. Any idea what I might do to fix this?

Comment: Please don't post answers if you don't understand the question. The question here is **not** _"In a piece of static HTML I have an image tag with a src attribute pointing to a resource, but it doesn't render"_, to which, if it were, _"Check the src attribute"_ would be a poor answer anyway.